# Queuing a build with variables failing with error TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs

I am using Rest API to queuing a new build. when the UNC path is like the one below it fails

```
\\xxx.com\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: c3442c5b-8ab6-4102-a22b-5d569cb7271c."
```

The only way it works is if I change the UNC to:

```
\\\\xxx.com\\global\\Engineering\\Builds\\Agile
```

What can be the reason for this issue and how can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
$BuildPath = "\\xxx.com\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile"
$BranchName = "v8.6.4x-SP"

$releaseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/Idu%20Client-Server/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0-preview"

$body = @{}

$body = @{
    definition = @{
        id = "26845"
    }
    parameters = '{"BranchName":"' + $BranchName + '","BuildPath":"' + $BuildPath + '"}'
}

$releaseResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $releaseUri -Body ($body | convertTo-json -Compress -Depth 10) -Headers $header
```

Comment: I solved the issue 
parameters = '{"BranchName":"' + $BranchName +'","BuildPath":' + ($BuildPath | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress) + '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code and now it's working

```
$BuildPath = "\\xxx.com\global\Engineering\Builds\Agile"
$BranchName = "v8.6.4x-SP"

$releaseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/Idu%20Client-Server/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0-preview"

$body = @{}

$body = @{
    definition = @{
        id = "26845"
    }
    parameters = '{"BranchName":"' + $BranchName +'","BuildPath":' + ($BuildPath | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress) + '}' 
}

$releaseResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $releaseUri -Body ($body | convertTo-json -Compress -Depth 10) -Headers $header
```